# How to pass a SELECT statement as an argument to a constructor expression in JPQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA class-based projection for constructing a DTO. The DTO represents an article. It has a `title` field and an `isWrittenByMe` field. The `isWrittenByMe` field should hold `true` when the parameter author is one of the article's authors and `false` otherwise.

I made a JPA repository and added a method that executes a custom JPQL query.

```java
   @Query("SELECT new com.example.learnjpql.dto.ArticleDTO(a.title, :author MEMBER OF a.authors) FROM Article a")
    List<ArticleDTO> getAllArticles(Author author);
```

Hibernate generated this query

```sql
Hibernate: select article0_.title as col_0_0_, ? in (authors1_.author_id) as col_1_0_ from article article0_ cross join article_authors2 authors1_ where article0_.id=authors1_.article_id
```

And this is the output of `getAllArticles`.

```
[ArticleDTO[title=Article 1, isAuthoredByMe=true], ArticleDTO[title=Article 1, isAuthoredByMe=false], ArticleDTO[title=Article 2, isAuthoredByMe=true], ArticleDTO[title=Article 3, isAuthoredByMe=false], ArticleDTO[title=Article 3, isAuthoredByMe=false], ArticleDTO[title=Article 4, isAuthoredByMe=false], ArticleDTO[title=Article 4, isAuthoredByMe=false], ArticleDTO[title=Article 5, isAuthoredByMe=false]]
```

It's outputting all entries in the join table, but I want the entries in the `Article` table

For instance, if the parameter author has written article 1 and article 3, I want a query that returns something like this:

| Title | isWrittenByMe |
| --- | --- |
| Article 1 | `true` |
| Article 2 | `false` |
| Article 3 | `true` |
| Article 4 | `false` |
| Article 5 | `false` |

I thought maybe instead of passing `:author MEMBER OF a.authors` to the constructor, I can pass a SELECT statement and that would run a seperate query for each entry, but I got an unexpected token error.

Please let me know if I'm missing something or using the wrong tool.

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Author {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "authors")
    private Set<Article> articles;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Author author))
            return false;
        return getId().equals(author.getId()) && getFirstname().equals(author.getFirstname()) && getLastname().equals(author.getLastname());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getFirstname(), getLastname());
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Author(id=" + this.getId() + ", firstname=" + this.getFirstname() + ", lastname=" + this.getLastname();
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
public class Article {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "article_authors2",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "article_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "author_id") })
    private Set<Author> authors;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Article article))
            return false;
        return getId().equals(article.getId()) && getTitle().equals(article.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getTitle());
    }
}
```

```java
public record ArticleDTO(
        String title,
        boolean isAuthoredByMe
) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Hibernate 6, predicates weren't usable as expressions, so you'd have to wrap your predicate into `case when ... then true else false end` i.e. your query becomes:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.learnjpql.dto.ArticleDTO(a.title, case when :author MEMBER OF a.authors then true else false end) FROM Article a")
List<ArticleDTO> getAllArticles(Author author);
```

alternatively, you can also use an explicit subquery:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.learnjpql.dto.ArticleDTO(a.title, case when exists (select 1 from a.authors sub where sub = :author) then true else false end) FROM Article a")
List<ArticleDTO> getAllArticles(Author author);
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, otherwise, it wouldn't even compile. I run your query and got the same result. Hibernate still loops through the join table, but I want it to loop through the Article table, and for each article entry, it should run another query for computing the `isWrittenByMe` field. I already know how to solve this using two separate repository methods (without projection) but I'm asking whether it's possible to do it with one method. I started looking into JPA Criteria API. It looks like it's more powerful than JPQL.

Comment: Now that you added the generated query, I can see that it generates wrong SQL for this predicate. Which Hibernate version are you using? Try updating to the latest Hibernate 5 version. JPQL/HQL is always more powerful and you can implement this with an explicit subquery, but chances are that if you update Hibernate, it will just work. I updated my answer to include the explicit subquery.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. I think you forgot the `then true else false end` for the case when statement. Is that optional for newer hibernate versions? I'm using Spring boot 2.7.4 and apparently hibernate 5.6.11.Final.

Comment: Oops, that was by mistake. I fixed the example.